# mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code in MyFile.php

```
$db= mysqli_connect("host","user","pw","db");//connect to db
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))//check connection
{echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
//Create a token for the unique link
$title= $_GET[apt_title];
$email= $_GET[mail_address];
$token = sha1(uniqid($email, true));
$time = $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"];
//prepare the query to be executed
$query = $db->prepare(
"INSERT INTO pending_users (email, token, title_apt, tstamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
$query->execute(
array(
    $title,
    $email,
    $token,
    $time
)
);
```

Error message:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /websites

How should I call `execute()` the right way?

Comment: Either use procuderal or object oriented style, do not mix them.

Comment: Now (2022) the documentation shows that it is perfectly ok to have an array as parameter. I still get this error as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to bind params before executing the query,
in procedural way do like this

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

if you are doing it like object oriented way after binding params

```
/* Execute the statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Docs link.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Answer (score 7):

Because  `mysqli::execute()` does not accept any parameters. Before calling it, you have to prepare the query and then bind the params to the query. Then you have to call the `execute()` method. So try like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare(
"INSERT INTO pending_users (email, token, title_apt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
$query->bind_param('ssss', $title, $email, $token, $time);
$query->execute();
```

For more check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: Then that may be due to your database connection problem..You have to replace `$con` variable with `$db` in the place you are checking connection.

Answer (score 4):

Passing parameters in `execute()` is available only as of PHP 8.1. You need to upgrade your PHP version or use the old `bind_param()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the manual for [mysqli::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php), you'll see that it does not accept any parameters.

> bool mysqli_stmt::execute ( void )

Instead, you should use [mysqli::bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind your parameters.